# Load multiple KEY/VALUE from Consul from different YML

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul

Currently I have consul configured to read a YML and load different properties as follows in bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: ${CONSUL_HOST}
      port: ${CONSUL_PORT}
      config:
        format: YAML
        acl-token: ${CONSUL_TOKEN}
        default-context: application
        prefix: config/
        name: application
        data-key: data/properties
```

This works correctly.

Now I have included another Key/Value in consul at the same level as "properties", which is as follows:

```
config/application/data/properties
config/application/data/newproperties
```

I am trying to be able to load both data keys at the same time so that I can keep the different settings separate, but I am not managing to properly configure bootstrap.yml for this to happen.

I've tried setting the type as FILES, but haven't gotten it to work.

Have any of you faced this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating and debugging the consul key/value behavior, it seems that it is not possible to read two different keys simultaneously.